# Viscosity solutions, $p \in D^+ u(x)$ holds if and only if$\ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $u \in C(U)$ and $x \in U$. How do I see that $p \in D^+ u(x)$ holds if and only if there is a $\varphi \in C^1(U)$ such that $D\varphi(x) = p$ and $u - \varphi$ has a local minimum at $x$?

Comment: How is $D^+u$ defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$D^{+}u$ indeed is the set of super-differentials of $u$ at a point $x$ which is defined as
\begin{equation}
 D^{+}u(x):=\left\{ 
 p\in U: \limsup_{y\rightarrow x}\frac{u(y)-u(x)-p\cdot (y-x)}{|y-x|}\leq 0\right\}.
\end{equation}
In other words, a vector $p\in U$ is a super-differential if and only if the plane
$y\mapsto u(x)+p\cdot(y-x)$ is tangent from above to the graph of $u$ at the point $x$.  Check Evans' PDE (page 584) and mimic the proof of the lemma about touching by a $C^1$ function you can proof it is equivalent to say that there is a $\varphi\in C^{1}(U)$ such that $D\varphi=p$ and $u-\varphi$ has a local minimal. Another good reference is Alberto Bressan and Benedetto Piccoli's Introduction to the Mathematical Theory of Control where you can find a clear illustration to viscosity solutions in Chapter 8.